# Was Susanna Clarke using any particular author's style for "Jonathan Strange & Mr Norrell"?

Tags: inspiration, jonathan-strange-and-mr-norrell, susanna-clarke

Susanna Clarke's excellent novel *Jonathan Strange & Mr Norrell* is written in a very convincing (at least to me) "19th-century literature" style. Not only the language used by the characters but also the sentence structure and storytelling style of the non-dialogue sections of the book feel very much like those of classical authors such as Austen, Hardy, or the Brontes.

Real connoisseurs of 19th-century literature will probably be shaking their heads at my lumping all of those authors together (so am I, to be honest). Hence my question: **was there any specific classical author whose writing style inspired Clarke's style in *Strange & Norrell*?**

Quotes from the author herself would probably be the best way of answering this, but if anyone can put together an answer based simply on textual analysis, I'll be mightily impressed.

Comment: To my knowledge it's an amalgam of various author's styles, rather than any one particular author. That's also what I get from Corey Olsen, who did an amazing series of lectures on the novel at Mythgard. Highly recommended, and free: http://mythgard.org/academy/jonathan-strange-and-mr-norrell/

Comment: @Joshua Sounds like you could make a good answer out of that!

Comment: I suspect she just is as perfectionist as Austen was... http://www.bbc.co.uk/nottingham/content/articles/2004/09/15/entertainment_books_susanna_clarke_feature.shtml

Comment: I didn't think I had enough but I just recollected a few things from the lecture...

Answer (score 7):

Corey Olsen discusses this a bit in his [lecture series at Mythgard](http://mythgard.org/academy/jonathan-strange-and-mr-norrell/). (I strongly recommend it: he's quite gifted at close analysis, plus it's free.)

He notes that most people compare it to Jane Austen, since that's the Regency author that most people are familiar with. It does fit her style well, but that of many other Georgian authors as well. In sum, he considers it an amalgam of various common tropes, rather than a direct stylistic copy of any particular author.

Comment: +1, but this answer could be improved by including some info from the interview Bookeater linked to in comments, where Clarke actually talks a bit about her inspirations.

Comment: That would explain why I didn't care for Clarke; I don't care for Austen's style either.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum: Yeah, Olsen goes on to talk about the long, elliptical style of the book. He considers that a feature, for the delicious way it echoes the actual writing of the period. But if you don't care for it, it's not gonna do you any good. In my personal experience I didn't get Austen at all until I saw the Ang Lee/Emma Thompson film of Sense & Sensibility. In high school I hated it because it was a satire of manners I'd never seen. Visualizing it helped it click.